# Let $Z\sim N(0, 1)$ then $E(f(Z))\le E(f(X))$ for any convex $f$ and any $X$ with unit variance.

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, entropy

I thought about this question purely out of curiosity. I have a feeling that it is true, but I can't prove it.

Standard normal distribution arises if we maximize the entropy among all absolutely continuous probability measures with mean $0$ and variance $1.$ But I want to show that $Z\preceq_{cx} X.$ That is, Suppose $f$ is a convex function and $Z\sim N(0, 1)$ and $X$ is some (absolutely continuous) random variable with zero mean and variance $1.$ I want to show that
$$E(f(Z))\le E(f(X)),$$
provided both sides are finite.

Comment: Let $f(x) = x^2$ and take $X$ to be uniform. I suspect it might be a counter-example.

Comment: I think $x^2$ can’t be a counter-example. It will simply give the $Var(Z)$ and $Var(X)$ and both are equal by assumption.

Comment: $Var(Z)=1$ but you can take $Var(X)<1$, right?

Comment: I am sorry, I mean the variance to be $1$ not less than $1.$

Comment: You can try for higher moments, it is known that $EZ^{2n}=(2n-1)!!$.

Comment: I think you can take a random variable with mean zero, variance 1, continuous distribution and infinite (or anyway large enough) fourth moment

Comment: @Exodd Large fourth moments are good for us, isn’t it? Don’t we want $X$ to have smaller higher order moments?

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho You are actually right, but with the same reasoning you can produce a variable with (almost) unit fourth moment, that is smaller than the Gaussian one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the random variables $X_k$ with densities
$$
f_k(x) = \mathbb{1}_{(\alpha,+\infty)}(|x|)c|x|^{-k}
$$
where
$$
k>3,\qquad
\alpha^2 = \frac{k-3}{k-1},  \qquad 2c = \frac{k-3}{\alpha^{3-k}}.
$$
They have mean 0 and variance 1 for every $k$, and their fourth moment (when $k>5$) is finite and it is
$$
\frac{(k-3)^2}{(k-3)^2-4}
$$
that is as large as you want when you take $k=5+\epsilon$.